# Is there any Openfire smack Alternative for Android chat?

Tags: android, xmpp, chat, openfire

I am working on Chat module for Android app. I configured Open fire as **XMPP** server and currently using smack library in client side development. I am facing some crucial problems regarding chat.
So is there any other open source alternate library of smack?
I search whole day for the solution. But I could not got proper.

Comment: what kind of problem are you facing ?

Comment: only one way chat is working. means if user 1 initiate chat then only user 1 can send message. user 2's message can not recieved.

Comment: here is my detailed problem description and my code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37164240/chat-works-only-one-way-with-smack-4-1-7-android

Comment: ok, i will take a look soon!

Answer (score 5):

I have used Applozic chat SDK. Its worked like a charm for me easy to integrate and customize.
The open source repo link is [here](https://github.com/AppLozic/Applozic-Android-SDK). Hope this helps.

Comment: I think applozic chat sdk is paid one.

Comment: yes its paid one after certain usage ..they do have a free plan also

Answer (score 1):

I am also still finding the solution.

I think Quickblock would be the alternative.

Reference:
https://community.igniterealtime.org/thread/52092

Answer (score 1):

Till now Smack is the only one java based open source XMPP client Implementation.So you have to use smack to use in android or you can use C++ client library like [swiften](http://www.isode.com/products/swiften.html) or [gloox](https://camaya.net/gloox/) as native. But in server side you can use any server developed following XMPP standard.